# IISExpress: Unable to automatically step into the server. the remote procedure cannot be debugged

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio, asmx, iis-express

I'm hosing a webservice in IISExpress and can browse to the endpoint using my browser so I know its alive. I'm writing a test application in WinForms and want to call a method on the service.

When I try and step into the call, I get this error.

**IISExpress: Unable to automatically step into the server. the remote procedure cannot be debugged.**

The webservice is set to be in debug mode, I'm wondering is there some setting which is preventing IISExpress from allowing debugging?

**Update:**
I'm wondering if this is because the Test app doesn't have any .pdb files loaded into memory as these are stored elsewhere within the webservice folder, NOT the test app bin folder.
I've tried to specify the folder of the bin folder where the app_code.pdb is located for the webservices, but still not luck.

So how is this done? I'm stumped.

**Update 2:**
Still haven't been able to get this to work after a week of looking into it.

So here are my basic requirements: I need a 1) WinForms app to 2) be able to make calls to different webservices and 3) be able to step into each service call. The services are hosted as sub-applications of a root website using IISExpress. The WinForm test app is making the web service calls, but IISExpress is started via a Nant task.  The webservices are old web site type projects, so they have app_code.dll files.  I've tried setting symbol paths up to point to the built pdb file, but I then get an error along the lines of:

"A matching symbol file was not found in this folder".

I never thought debugging webservices would be this difficult?!?

Comment: Are you able to run the webservice and WinForms application on the same server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using IISExpress to host about 6 asmx webservices at localhost and I want the win forms app to test each one in turn. Each web service has it's own deployed folder with app_code.dll. The test app doesn't know anything about the symbols so I've added it into the symbols folder in VS - still no luck.

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean "when I try to step into the call"?  Are you trying to step with the WinForms application in the webservice call?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to test the webservice?

Comment: On the call to the webservice (from my WinForms test app), I have a breakpoint.  As soon as I stop, I hit F11 to step-into the service.  I'm assuming the app_code.dll should then be operative, but VS doesn't want to step in.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to do white-box testing.  Have you considered black-box testing instead?  Would you be able to test sufficiently using black-box testing?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box_testing.

Comment: So, instead of having to step right into the web service directly, you could just call the web service from a client and verify if the results are what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

1) Reference the DLL of your webservice in your test project.

2) IISExpress is a completely different application then your winforms application, just having the DLLs referenced still won't automatically allow you to step into your web service code. You need to attach to the IISExpress.exe process. When you start your winforms project, Hit Debug...Attach to Process and choose IISExpress.exe. *Now* you should be able to actually step into your web service code.

Comment: Still haven't been able to get this to work after a week of looking into it. So here are my basic requirements: I need a 1) WinForms app to 2) be able to make calls to different webservices and 3) be able to step into each service call. The services are hosted as sub-applications of a root website using IISExpress. The WinForm test app is making the webservice call, but IISExpress is started via a Nant task.

Comment: And did you try the two steps above?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work still. Why is this so difficult to get working? I'm running the IISExpress againt .NET2 framework and against a deployed web service with app_code.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a late response but it's something I've run into (especially after having stepped away from a WCF project for long periods of time).

Make sure you have your breakpoint set in your "server-side" service class code...and not in your "client-side" calling code. This is so the server side service has the necessary debug info (your breakpoint) compiled into the .pdb file on the server.

Comment: I can't remember how I got this to work in the end. I'm not sure if my webservices were getting called from the release instead of the debug locations. You probably have a valid point too.